# Question on rights to patent

Tags: licensing

In reference to the patent: [US20040108409](https://www.google.com/patents/US20040108409)

I would like to purchase rights to this patent if the inventor is interested.  Can you please point me in the right direction?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a name and address on all [applications](http://appft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PG01&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/srchnum.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=20040108409.PGNR.) ;-)